# UnsatisfiedLinkError while using JNI

Tags: java, c++, dll, compilation, java-native-interface

I get the following error while trying to program JNI in C++.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\JNI examples\cfiles\hello.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at HelloJNI.<clinit>(HelloJNI.java:3)
Could not find the main class: HelloJNI.  Program will exit.
```

The error is only popped for .dll file generated from a .cpp file.

If the .dll file is generated from a .c file it doesn't show any error gives the correct output.

The D:\JNI folder exists and works fine for .c file. I used GCC vesion 4.7.0 compiler to generate the dll file.
Hello JNI.java

```
public class HelloJNI {
static {
  System.loadLibrary("hello"); // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
}
// A native method that receives nothing and returns void
private native void sayHello();

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new HelloJNI().sayHello();  // invoke the native method
}
}
```

HelloJNI.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
printf("Hello World!\n");

cout<<"Hello";

return;
}
```

> gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"\include" -I"\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.cpp

Comment: It looks like this could be a problem with how Windows finds binaries. Does `D:\JNI` exist?

Comment: What is your compiler? Show source code for the native function (and the java declaration for it). How do you export the function? Are you compiling your cpp with the same bitness? (32/64). In short: give more infos

Comment: I have added the information as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `g++` instead of `gcc` compiler. It's true these are generally aliases, but `g++` takes care of standard libraries and little ABI differences between <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>C++</kbd>.

Also, note that JNI is essentially a <kbd>C</kbd> interface, therefore you need

```
 extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
```

Sometimes, the `extern "C"` attribute is inherited from the `javah`-generated <kbd>.h</kbd> file.

I sincerely don't understand why the standard `jni.h` file cannot define `JNIEXPORT` to include this attribute.

Comment: I had my problem solved the error was due to wrong dll file mine was a 64 bit system gcc created a 32 bit dll and so the dll was invalid used a visual C++ compiler to generate a dll file in 64bit worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I had my problem solved the error was due to wrong dll file mine was a 64 bit system but the gcc created a 32 bit dll and so the dll was invalid while runtinme. I then used a visual C++ compiler to generate a dll file in 64bit worked fine.